# Getting error on recorder.start()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, mediarecorder

I am new in android development. When i am recording a call in my service class the recorder.start()  is getting IllegalStateException.Here is my Logcat:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException.android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
```

my serivce class is:--

public class RecordService extends Service {

```
private MediaRecorder recorder = null;
private String phoneNumber = null;

private String fileName;
private boolean onCall = false;
private boolean recording = false;
private boolean silentMode = false;
private boolean onForeground = false;
private int currentFormat = 0;
private String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "Testing_recording";
String file_exts[] = { AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_MP3,
        AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_MP4, AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_3GP };
static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_MP3 = ".mp3";
static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_3GP = ".3gp";
static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_MP4 = ".mp4";
private int output_formats[] = { MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4,
        MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP };

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "RecordService onStartCommand");
    if (intent != null) {
        int commandType = intent.getIntExtra("commandType", 0);
        if (commandType != 0) {
            if (commandType == Constants.RECORDING_ENABLED) {
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, "RecordService RECORDING_ENABLED");
                silentMode = intent.getBooleanExtra("silentMode", true);
                if (!silentMode && phoneNumber != null && onCall
                        && !recording)
                    commandType = Constants.STATE_START_RECORDING;

            } else if (commandType == Constants.RECORDING_DISABLED) {
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, "RecordService RECORDING_DISABLED");
                silentMode = intent.getBooleanExtra("silentMode", true);
                if (onCall && phoneNumber != null && recording)
                    commandType = Constants.STATE_STOP_RECORDING;
            }

            if (commandType == Constants.STATE_INCOMING_NUMBER) {
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, "RecordService STATE_INCOMING_NUMBER");
                startService();
                if (phoneNumber == null)
                    phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra("phoneNumber");

                silentMode = intent.getBooleanExtra("silentMode", true);
            } else if (commandType == Constants.STATE_CALL_START) {
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, "RecordService STATE_CALL_START");
                onCall = true;

                if (phoneNumber != null && onCall
                        && !recording) {
                    startService();
                    startRecording(intent);
                }
            } else if (commandType == Constants.STATE_CALL_END) {
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, "RecordService STATE_CALL_END");
                onCall = false;
                phoneNumber = null;
                stopAndReleaseRecorder();
                recording = false;
                stopService();
            } else if (commandType == Constants.STATE_START_RECORDING) {
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, "RecordService STATE_START_RECORDING");
                if ( phoneNumber != null && onCall) {
                    startService();
                    startRecording(intent);
                }
            } else if (commandType == Constants.STATE_STOP_RECORDING) {
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, "RecordService STATE_STOP_RECORDING");
                stopAndReleaseRecorder();
                recording = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

/**
 * in case it is impossible to record
 */
private void terminateAndEraseFile() {
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "RecordService terminateAndEraseFile");
    stopAndReleaseRecorder();
    recording = false;
    // deleteFile();
}

private void stopService() {
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "RecordService stopService");
    stopForeground(true);
    onForeground = false;
    this.stopSelf();
}

private void deletseFile() {
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "RecordService deleteFile");
    FileHelper.deleteFile(fileName);
    fileName = null;
}

private void stopAndReleaseRecorder() {
    if (recorder == null)
        return;
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "RecordService stopAndReleaseRecorder");
    boolean recorderStopped = false;
    boolean exception = false;

    try {
        recorder.stop();
        recorderStopped = true;
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e(Constants.TAG, "IllegalStateException");
        e.printStackTrace();
        exception = true;
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        Log.e(Constants.TAG, "RuntimeException");
        exception = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(Constants.TAG, "Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
        exception = true;
    }
    try {
        recorder.reset();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(Constants.TAG, "Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
        exception = true;
    }
    try {
        recorder.release();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(Constants.TAG, "Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
        exception = true;
    }

    recorder = null;
    if (exception) {
        // deleteFile();
    }
    if (recorderStopped) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,
                this.getString(R.string.receiver_end_call),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "RecordService onDestroy");
    stopAndReleaseRecorder();
    stopService();
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void startRecording(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "RecordService startRecording");
    boolean exception = false;
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();

    try {

        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_UPLINK);
        // recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(output_formats[currentFormat]);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        // fileName = FileHelper.getFilename(phoneNumber);

        recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());
        recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
        recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);

        OnErrorListener errorListener = new OnErrorListener() {
            public void onError(MediaRecorder arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
                Log.e(Constants.TAG, "OnErrorListener " + arg1 + "," + arg2);
                terminateAndEraseFile();
            }
        };
        recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);

        OnInfoListener infoListener = new OnInfoListener() {
            public void onInfo(MediaRecorder arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
                Log.e(Constants.TAG, "OnInfoListener " + arg1 + "," + arg2);
                terminateAndEraseFile();
            }
        };
        recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);

        recorder.prepare();
        // Sometimes prepare takes some time to complete
         Thread.sleep(2000); 

         try {
                recorder.start();
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                    Log.w("sf", t);
                }


    //  recorder.start();

        /*new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                // recorder.stop();

                if (null != recorder) {

                    recorder.stop();
                    recorder.reset();
                    recorder.release();
                    System.out.println("hello helloo");
                    recorder = null;
                }

                Log.e("Ho rha hai", "goodndnd");
            }

        }, 40000);*/



        recording = true;
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "RecordService recorderStarted");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "recording is strated ", 2000).show();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e(Constants.TAG, "IllegalStateException");
        e.printStackTrace();
        exception = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(Constants.TAG, "IOException");
        e.printStackTrace();
        exception = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(Constants.TAG, "Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
        exception = true;
    }

    if (exception) {
        terminateAndEraseFile();
    }

    if (recording) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,
                this.getString(R.string.receiver_start_call),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    } else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,
                this.getString(R.string.record_impossible),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
}
private MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener errorListener = new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
    public void onError(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
    }
};

private MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener infoListener = new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
    public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
    }
};

private void startService() {
    if (!onForeground) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "RecordService startService");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        // intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        // intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getBaseContext(), 0, intent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                getBaseContext())
                .setContentTitle(
                        this.getString(R.string.notification_title))
                .setTicker(this.getString(R.string.notification_ticker))
                .setContentText(this.getString(R.string.notification_text))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setOngoing(true)
                .getNotification();

        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

        startForeground(1337, notification);
        onForeground = true;
    }
}

private String getFilename() {
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MMM_yy_HH_mm_ss");
    String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(System
            .currentTimeMillis()));
    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "Rec_" + dateString + file_exts[currentFormat]);
}
```

}

and broadcast receiver is this:--

public class MyPhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
private String phoneNumber;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
    String extraState = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "MyPhoneReciever phoneNumber "+phoneNumber);

    if (MainActivity.updateExternalStorageState() == Constants.MEDIA_MOUNTED) {
        try {
            SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(
                    Constants.LISTEN_ENABLED, 0);
            boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", true);
            if (extraState != null) {
                if (extraState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context,
                            RecordService.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("commandType",
                            Constants.STATE_CALL_START);
                    context.startService(myIntent);
                } else if (extraState
                        .equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context,
                            RecordService.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("commandType",
                            Constants.STATE_CALL_END);
                    context.startService(myIntent);
                } else if (extraState
                        .equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                    if (phoneNumber == null)
                        phoneNumber = intent
                                .getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context,
                            RecordService.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("commandType",
                            Constants.STATE_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                    myIntent.putExtra("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
                    myIntent.putExtra("silentMode", silent);
                    context.startService(myIntent);
                }
            } else if (phoneNumber != null) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, RecordService.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("commandType",
                        Constants.STATE_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                myIntent.putExtra("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
                myIntent.putExtra("silentMode", silent);
                context.startService(myIntent);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(Constants.TAG, "Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}